# Winform doesn't fully dispose

Tags: c#, .net

I have a form Menu that won't fully dispose. Below is the complete form code. It's part of a larger system so other forms open and close before Menu is first opened.

There's a form timer that fires every second and prints whether the form is disposed or not. There's a button that opens another form, Search, and closes Menu. Search also has a timer that prints whether it is disposed or not.

When Menu opens, the debug output is as expected

```
*********** (in main menu): Disposed False
*********** (in main menu): Disposed False
```

When I click, I get timer ticks for both Menu and Search

```
*********** (in main): Disposed True
*************** (in search) Disposed False
```

It shows that the first instance of Menu is disposed but obviously the timer is still running. When I exit Search and Main is opened, there are now two Main timers running

```
*********** (in main): Disposed True
*********** (in main): Disposed False
```

I can keep doing this (click to open Search and exit) and the number of Main timers running keeps increasing. I'm perplexed. Here's the code for Main

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Gui
{
public partial class Menu : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
    private Button button1;
    private IContainer components;

    public Menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Menu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("*********** (in main): Disposed {0}", IsDisposed);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var search = new Search();
        search.Show();
        Close();
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this.timer1.Enabled = true;
        this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
        this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 17);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 32);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // Menu
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(282, 253);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "Menu";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Menu_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So you keep referencing the Form? How could it be disposed off then?

Comment: Please show the code from `Search` that reopens the main form.  My guess is that you are creating a new instance of the form instead of showing the existing one again.  Especially since you call close on it instead of hiding it.

Comment: @TaW - Disposal has nothing to do with having a reference.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot if he's referencing the instance then its not disposed, otherwise it would throw an exception.

Comment: @Blearyeye I would implement your own dispose override to handle disposal of timers

Comment: @Wobbles - That's up to the class implementation. Obviously having an `IsDisposed` property would be pretty useless if it just throws an exception when it should return true. You are free to keep referencing a disposed object if you like. Nothing forcing you not to.

Comment: `Close` doesn't necessarily dispose of the form. Otherwise you'd not be able to re-show the form. Call `Dispose` instead to really dispose of the form. The fact you get multiple outputs from main is probably due to the fact that you create a new main form in your search form. So actually it looks like multiple outputs from one form while it's actually one output from multiple instances.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot You cannot reference a property or field (the timer) inside of a disposed class.... It WILL return an exception.

Comment: Perhaps using a singleton pattern would be helpful here.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/5cbf16a9-1721-4861-b7c0-ea20cf328d48 Calling Form.Show() then Form.Close() will call the dispose automatically.

Comment: My guess is, tho I dont have much experience with `Forms.Timer` is that the Timer object cannot clean itself up and must be managed by manually disposing it in a `override dispose()`.

Comment: Events are handled by the Timer Tick in the computer.  So you have to unregister (-=) the timer event from the class that register the time.  The event can't be unregistered by the timer itself because it doesn't own the registration.  You are getting an exception because the class is being disposed but the event is still registers.  So when the timer fires it has no code to respond to the event.

Comment: @Wobbles - There is no guarantee anywhere that anything *must* throw an exception due to disposal. `Dispose()` is just a method and doesn't do anything 'magic'. It *is* probably good class design to throw an exception after disposal, as why would you want to use an object after you've stated you are done with it? But not required in any way. If you need reinforcement, feel free to try: `Form1 Test = new Form1(); Test.Dispose(); Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", Test.IsDisposed, Test.Location);`

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot You are missing the fact that he is accessing an disposable object INSIDE the form, `Test.timer1` reference WILL return an exception on a properly disposed form.

Answer (score 3):

```
    this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
```

It looks like you copy/pasted the content of a Designer.cs file of a form class.  The InitializeComponent() method is certainly boilerplate.  But you didn't do it right, you forgot to actually *use* the `this.components` member.  Which exists for only one reason, disposing any components that the form class uses.  Like timer1.  It is automatic for any controls you drop on the form, they can be found back through the form's Controls member but components need extra help.

So don't just copy/paste InitializeComponent(), you **must** copy/paste the Dispose() method as well:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing && (components != null)) {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

And the timer now stops ticking when you close the form.

Comment: How right you are. I don't know how that happened; I didn't cut & paste, it just showed up there somehow in Menu.cs file. I was a little surprised but left it alone. Anyway, that takes care of the matter very nicely, thanks.